# Multiply columns of Excel table using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to multiply values in two columns of a table and display it in another column.

Since this process has to be repeated for multiple columns, how should I go about referencing columns using column headers? Any help would be appreciated.

The logic would be as follows:

```
ListColumns(x) = ListColumns(x - 1) * ListColumns(x - 3)
```

This is within a loop where the value of x changes.

Comment: If you mean `x` represents a different column name each loop you can place your column headers into a comma separated list and then use `Split` function to turn into an array to loop through.

Comment: you should add more info and examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving what you are after.

1st: Let's suppose `x = 4`, so you want to multiply column A and C and store result in D column. Simply put formula `= A1 * C1` in `D1` and drag it all the way down.

2nd: Using VBA, more generic:

```
Sub MultiplyCoulmns()
    Dim resultColumn As Long 'this is x
    resultColumn = 4 'just for example, change it to whatever you need
    'alternatively, specify column header
    Dim header As String
    header = "SomeColumn"
    resultColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(header, Range("A1:Z1"), 0)
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, resultColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Cells(i, resultColumn) = Cells(i, resultColumn - 1) * Cells(i, resultColumn - 3)
    Next
End Sub
```